# Decoding Regex format check

Tags: php, regex

So I'm doing this php puzzle/challenge and the task is to find a string that matches this format:

```
/^[\w][-.]+([A-B])[^a-z]{3}\.[0-9]{2,4}$/
```

But I can´t find any documentation what exactly this part means:

```
[-.]+
```

The other parts I interpreted hopefully correctly as the following:

```
/^[\w]
```

Any word character

```
[^a-z]{3}
```

Not a-z 3times e.g. ABC should be accepted

```
\.[0-9]{2,4}$
```

It has to end with a number from 0-9 repeated 2 to 4 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.A123.12` or `a-.-.-A123.12` are matched.

Explanation:

`/^[\w][-.]+([A-B])[^a-z]{3}\.[0-9]{2,4}$/` matches from beginning to end:

```
Qty | Characters
----------------------------------------
1   | word character
1+  | "-" or "."
1   | "A" or "B"
3   | all characters apart from a-z
1   | "."
2-4 | figures 0-9
```

Answer (score 1):

`[-.]` means match either a literal `-` or a literal `.`, and the `+` means match one or more of those, so `[-.]+` means a string containing any number (but at least one) of `-`s and `.`s and nothing else.

Your interpretation of the other pieces is mostly correct, with these notes:

1. The ^ and $ at the beginning and end mean that you can't have anything in the string before or after what the rest of the regex matches.
2. There needs to be a literal dot before the ending numbers that you mention.

Note that in the future, you can use regex tester sites like https://regex101.com/ to see exactly what any regex or piece of regex does.